# List of methods used in layout action?

Tags: layout, blocks, theme

Hi could any one tell

> methods used in in layout file and its functionality in magento

for example

```
<action method=”insert”>
<action method=”setImgSrc”>
```

can any one list defalut methods used in layout file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1.You can use any public methods of block (or it's parent blocks) class in layout, for ex.:**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
```

Block class of `catalog/product_list` is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`. And parent class of this block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` has method `addColumnCountLayoutDepend` with two arguments:

```
//<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend">'empty'      '6'
  public function addColumnCountLayoutDepend( $pageLayout, $columnCount)
  {
      $this->_columnCountLayoutDepend[$pageLayout] = $columnCount;
      return $this;
   }
```

We can dispatch this method using `<action method="doSomeMethod"><param1>value</param1><param2>value</param2></action>`. By the way this is actual methods of classes.

**2.You can set any data to the block using magick getter and setters of Magento Object: `setSomeData($value)`. Because of all blocks of Magento inherits from Varien_Object class:**

```
<block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
    <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
    <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
    <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
</block>
```

This is same with `$block->setImgSrc('images/media/col_left_callout.jpg')` and in template file you can use `$this->getImgSrc()` to retrive already setted data.

**3.Dispath methods via reference:**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
</reference>
```

`footer_links` block is defined in `page.xml` layout:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
```

Open block class `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`:

```
public function addLink($label, $url='', title='', ....)
{
   //....
}
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Nice explanation. I may add that anything that starts with `uns` is also valid. It will call `unsetData`.

Comment: This.  Also, if you're interested is browsing the available methods by block type, you ma be interested in my old developer manual extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer-manual.html